# How to open weka GUI using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, weka

I want to open the weka GUI when I press a pushbutton of Matlab GUI. I could do it using "!weka.exe" only if the Weka had an .exe file to run; but as it doesn't have an .exe file, so how to open it using Matlab?

Comment: How do you start weka normally? I assume it's some shortcut to `java -jar weka.jar`, maybe with some additional parameters? Use the same command.

Comment: [status result] = system('java -jar weka.jar');

It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

status result] = system('java -jar weka.jar'); It worked.